# URL Filtering on ASA5506

Tags: cisco-asa

I need some help. I need to allow a single network (for example only 10.10.10.0/24) access to 10 url (*.norton.com*.symantec.com etc...). Everything else has to be deny.I don't know what i have to do to make this work. How i can apply this to acl? Аny help will be appreciated. So... I have:
 •regex objects 
"regex url_regex_1 "norton.com".
• class-map:

```
class-map type inspect http match-all allow-url-class
 match not request header host regex url_regex_1
 match not request header host regex url_regex_2
 match not request header host regex url_regex_3 ...etc

policy-map type inspect http allow-url-policy
 parameters
 class allow-url-class
  drop-connection

policy-map allow-user-url-policy
 class allow-user-class
  inspect http allow-url-policy
```

---

Ok, got it. So deleted IPs and other information. Replaced all networks with "X", only where is the network that i need, i put  10.10.10.0 (example). This device isn't configured by me. It's a client device and i have to fixed this issue...

Comment: Please paste in your configuration, including how and where you applied it. It would be best to include the full (sanitized) configuration, and use the Preformatted-text option (`{}`).

Comment: I tried to paste all configure, it's its look awful. Can i attach .txt file here?

Comment: Use the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). Paste the configuration into the question, highlight it, and click on the button. It will fix it for you, and it will create a scroll box for any wide or long configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to complicate this by using REGEX.  It's easily accomplished using an FQDN-based ACE and some objects/object-groups, provided you have DNS defined on your ASA already and the server it's pointing to has access to resolve public addresses.  Here's a quick example of what you'd do.

```
object network SOURCE-NETWORK
  subnet 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0

object network FQDN-1
  fqdn <fqdn of a site> (ex. www.facebook.com)

object-group network ALLOW-LIST
  network-object object FQDN-1

access-list <ACL NAME> extended permit tcp object SOURCE-NETWORK object-group ALLOW-LIST eq 443
```

That would allow that source network access to any of the FQDN entries listed in the object group on port 443. You could add a deny after that access-list entry for the source network if you want to block them from accessing anything else.

```
Example: access-list <ACL NAME> extended deny tcp object SOURCE-NETWORK any eq 443
```

Just keep adding more FQDN objects and add them to the object-group if you need more allowed sites.

Feel free to rename the objects and such as needed.